# ActionController::UnknownFormat in CommentsController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a Library Management app and stuck in comment model

So, this is my relationship for comment model:

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
       has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    end

    class Book < ApplicationRecord
       has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    end

    class Comment < ApplicationRecord
       belongs_to :user
       belongs_to :book
       validates :content, presence: true, allow_blank: false
    end
```

comments_controller.rb

```
    class CommentsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :load_book, only: :create

    def index
      @q = Comment.ransack(params[:q]) 
  @comments = @q.result.page(params[:page])
    end

    def new;
    end 

    def create   
     @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
     @comment.user_id = current_user.id
     @comment.book_id = params[:book_id]

     if @comment.save
     flash[:success] = "create_success"
     redirect_to book_path(@book)

    end

    private
    def comment_params
       params.require(:comment).permit(:user_id, :book_id, :content)
    end

    def load_book
      @book = Book.find_by(params[:id])
      return if @book
      flash[:danger] = "books.load_book.error_message"
      redirect_to root_path
     end
     end
```

in books_controller.rb

```
    def show
        @comment = Comment.new
end
```

app/view/books/show.html.erb

```
    <% provide :title, @book.name %>
    <h1><%= @book.name %></h1>

    <div class="container">
    <dl>
    <dt>Author:</dt><dd><%= link_to @book.author.name, @book.author 
    %></dd><br>
    <dt>Category:</dt><dd>
    <% @book.categories.each do |c|%>
          <%= link_to c.name, c%> |
    <% end %>
    <dt>Publisher:</dt><dd><%= @book.publisher %></dd><br>
    <dt>Page:</dt><dd><%= @book.page %></dd><br>
    <dt>Quantity:</dt><dd><%= @book.quantity %></dd><br>

    </dl>
    <aside>
      <section>
       <%= render 'comments/form' %>  
      </section>
    </aside>
    </div>
```

app/view/comments/_form.html.erb

```
    <h3>post_comment</h3>
    <p>
     <%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_area :content %>
      <%= f.submit "post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
     <% end %>
    </p>
```

And the browser show this Error:

```
    Missing template comments/new, application/new with {:locale=> 
    [:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, 
    :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * 
    "/home/default/ProjectRails/app/views"
```

This is the first time I make a many to many relationship, is it ok or the problem is in another part ?

Answer (score 2):

As clearly mentioned in the error message

```
CommentsController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant.
```

You need to create the file `app/view/comments/index.html.erb` with some content